# Expect a function to change e.g. the length of array

Tags: javascript, jestjs

Here is a common use case. We want to test this `removeItem` function.

```js
// items.js
items = [/* .... */];
function removeItem(id) {
  // remove item with given id from `items`
}
```

I want to write something like:

```js
// test.js
expect(() => removeItem(7)).toChange(() => items.length);
```

How do I write this with `jest`?

Another example of what-could-be, in ruby we have a nice API for this:

```rb
# test.rb
expect { removeItem(7) }.to(change { items.length }.from(1).to(0))
```

EDIT: I am, of course, aware of the following approach, and I'm specifically looking for something with less duplication.

```js
// test.js
expect(items).toHaveLength(1);
removeItem(7);
expect(items).toHaveLength(0);
```

Comment: I think you just run `removeItem` and `expect(items.length).toBe(2)`, where 2 is one less that the length was before calling `removeItem`...

Answer (score 2):

Jest keeps it simple:

```
expect(items).toHaveLength(1);
removeItem(7);
expect(items).toHaveLength(0);
```

It's possible to implement `toChange` with [custom matcher](https://github.com/jest-community/jest-extended/issues/253#issuecomment-612202499).

Comment: Thanks for the "custom matcher" link!

Answer (score -1):

I'd suggest you to assert that the array should not contain an object with `id: 7`. This way in case of test failure you're have much better description of why the test have failed

example:

```
test('should remove the item from array', () => {
  expect(items).not.toContainEqual(
    expect.objectContaining({
      id: 7
    })
  )
})
```

which, in case of failure will output something like:

[image]

[demo](https://repl.it/repls/PleasantBouncyDefinition)